# How to get CaretLocation of text using swt styledText

Tags: swt

I need CaretLocation of text by using SWT Styledtext.

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate. Add a real question to your post. Maybe show some of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't [`getCaretOffset()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/StyledText.html#getCaretOffset%28%29) do what you want?

```
StyledText text = ...
int position = text.getCaretOffset();
```